# How to create Android library jar if not using resources?

Tags: android, jar, android-manifest, android-permissions

I am creating an Android library, and I would like to create a distributable jar without revealing source code. The library does not use resources like layouts, images, etc. I understand that I can just copy the .jar automatically generated in the bin folder of an Eclipse Android project if I check 'is Library' under project properties.

Is there anything else I should be aware of? How does the client project know which permissions my library requires. Should I include those permissions in the Manifest of my library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that I can just copy the .jar automatically generated in the bin folder of an Eclipse Android project if I check 'is Library' under project properties.

I wouldn't, as you don't know how that JAR was created, and you don't know how that JAR might change as the tools change. That JAR is a side-effect of Android's *internal* build process and is not designed to be a production artifact. Create your own production JAR yourself (e.g., Ant `<jar>` task).

> How does the client project know which permissions my library requires.

You tell them via well-written documentation.

> Should I include those permissions in the Manifest of my library?

Since your JAR does not contain your manifest, that will not help.

Comment: Can I still import external jars into my library if I make my library a jar?

Comment: @ask: The users of your JAR are welcome to reference other external JARs. If your JAR depends upon other JARs, you would need to tell them about those other JARs, so they know to download them and put them in `libs/`. In this regard, JARs in Android are not significantly different than JARs in more traditional Java environments.

Comment: I'm searching for resources to create my own closed source library. It uses Android classes like the ConnectivityManager, etc. , so it's not purely using just the Java API. Do you know how I can go about doing this? Links are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @ask: Create a regular Android project (e.g., library project) and create your own JAR with the results (e.g., Ant `<jar>` task). Most of my CWAC projects fit this model, such as https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager and https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless and https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-layouts